# How to force new deployment of multiple ECS services?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cli

I'm trying to force a new deployment of multiple ECS services in a single command

I can't see any options from the AWS docs for "aws ecs update-service" that will allow me to restart all ECS services containing a particular tag or any that are using a particular task definition. Being able to do that would be ideal

What options do I have, using aws cli to be able to restart multiple services at once?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to do that in a single AWS CLI command. That is not a feature exposed by AWS. If you need a "single command" to do that, then write a script to perform this task. Running the script will then be your single command.

Comment: Do you have any pointers of which aws cli commands would help me do this? I'd already part looked into doing this but still, there didn't seem to be anything simple that allowed me to specify tag/task definition to list the services

Comment: All AWS CLI commands allow filtering the output by values such as tags: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html